# Is this a known bug in Xcode? My cursor icon doesn't change when it should

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm learning iOS programming with Xcode and this bug is driving me nuts. I'm on the latest version of Xcode. Whenever my cursor changes to the "Adjust size" icon, it won't change back to the normal "Pointer" icon as expected.

[Here's a video of the bug](https://streamable.com/vlgakv). Notice that when I cross slowly over the vertical edge of the pane, the cursor keeps the "Adjust size" icon. This only happens on some of these pane edges.

I do have several tweaks installed on my Mac, since the OS by default is terrible for productivity. But this isn't happening with any other programs.

Comment: Yes. It is a bug. It happens to me all the time. We'll just have to wait for an update.

Comment: Very annoying bug for me too.

Comment: I also randomly get a caret all the time.